# What is the $Q_y$ transition in a bacteriochlorophyll?

Tags: biology, quantum-chemistry, dipole

Bacteriochlorophyll (BChl) are pigments that occur in the photosynthetic mechanisms of bacteria. I am studying some papers on the excitonic properties of BChl's, and the term $Q_y$ transition comes up a lot, but I haven not found any explanation of its meaning.

Can someone explain to me the meaning of this term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $Q_x$ and $Q_y$ transitions are electronic excitations in the conjugated $\pi$ orbitals of the Bchl a molecule. They involve two different sets of conjugated bonds. The $Q_x$ involves a shorter chain of conjugated bonds so it occurs at a higher energy/frequency. I couldn't find a really good diagram to show which bonds are involved in the in the $Q_x$ and which in the $Q_y$ excitations, but figure 1 in [this paper](http://dosequis.colorado.edu/Courses/InsaneMembrane/papers/PS1-PSII-LHC%27s/The%20Crystallographic%20Structure%20of%20the%20B800-820%20LH3%20Light-Ha.pdf) has a reasonable illustration.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand. I should mention that I am a student just starting to learn about these things. What are the conjugated $\pi$ orbitals? What is a conjugated bond? ... I am sure your answer is very good but I understand like 10% of it.

Comment: If you could reference me to some introductory material somewhere that would also be great.

Comment: Gosh, you're asking for an explanation of a huge area of chemistry :-) Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_bond for an explanation of what a $\pi$ orbital is, then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugated_system for an explanation of how $\pi$ bonds can conjugate.